# Handling race condition in Google Sheets

Tags: django, concurrency, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am using gspread library to access and edit google sheets via python. Is there a good way to handle race conditions ( not necessarily using gspread only ) when there may be multiple workers writing to the same sheet.

I use a Django server which will accept requests to edit or update the sheet, in case multiple requests come, can I use some locking mechanism so that I have only one worker accessing the sheet at a time, while other will keep waiting to acquire the lock and get the access when the previous workers are done editing the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) to access and modify protected ranges and sheets. It was also reported as [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756264) (fixed).

> **A protected range can protect either a static range of cells or a named range. A protected sheet may include unprotected regions.**
>
> Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
> var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
> var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
> ```
>
> Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
>
> ```
> var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
> protection.addEditor(me);
> protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
> if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
>   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
> }
> ```
>
> Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has permission to edit.
>
> ```
>    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
>     var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
>     for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
>       var protection = protections[i];
>       if (protection.canEdit()) {
>         protection.remove();
>       }
>     }
> ```
>
> Protect the active sheet, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
>
> ```
> var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
> var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected sheet');
> ```
>
> Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
>
> ```
> var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
> protection.addEditor(me);
> protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
> if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
>   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The above code will support only one user accessing region of the sheet, but in my application, there is only one user ( I use google auth private key of a google account ) to edit the sheet. 
however, multiple requests could come for editing the sheet by different clients. Wanted to know if we have a locking mechanism on top such that only when one client completes editing the sheet, other clients' request is taken. 
Thanks a lot for the answer, will try to see if I can fit in my present problem.